# What is the possible way to return a whole string in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to return a string saying `'sunday'` in MATLAB. I have the following code:

```
function name = dayname(a) 
    value = rem(a,7); 

    if value == 0 
        name = disp('munday');
    end 
end
```

the return value should be stored in `name` however I am getting the following error:

> Too many output arguments

What am I doing wrong and how do I return a string in MATLAB?

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: And show us the full code that replicates the error. Matlab's documentation is excellent. I recommend that you start there if you're new. Here's the [page on function basics](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-basics.html).

Comment: to many output arguments

Comment: @cowboy Do you assign `n = 'sunday'` inside of the function and then do `str = name(whatever)` outside of it?

Comment: function name = dayname(a)

value = rem(a,7);
 if value == 0
     n= disp('munday')
     
 end
end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `disp` does not return an output argument, it simply displays the input on the command line.

If you want to return a string, then simply assign the string to the output variable

```
function name = dayname(a)
    value = rem(a, 7);

    if value == 0
        name = 'munday';
    end

    %...
end
```

A better way to do this would be to create a cell array of all of the names and then index into that

```
function name = dayname(a)
    names = {'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'};

    index = rem(a, 7) + 1;

    name = names{index};
end
```